# SignalR Client won't print the Queue Position

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have the Following Code for my SignalR Client. Based on my knowledge so far, this code should print anything that is send by "noitfyQueuePosition" event.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Hub...");

var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:7178/queueHub").Build();

hubConnection.Closed += async (error) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed. Reconnecting...");
    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
};

hubConnection.On<string>("notifyQueuePosition", (queueCount) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Message received from server: {queueCount}");
});

try
{
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to SignalR Hub.");

    await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("JoinQueue", "fj294ij29r8jv09258jwr0fj2508f2trvjh2");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error connecting to SignalR Hub: {ex.Message}");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm using an instance of my hub in another class and using the following method to send queue count to every connection in my server.
"**await _queueHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("notifyQueuePosition", queueCount);**"

The problem is that Queue Count isn't getting printed on my Client's Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a background service and reproduced your issue, and I get the error like below. The error maybe same as your side, if not, please check the *Suggestion* below, it my help you to print the more details like my picture.

[image]

Then I add the `Newtonsoft.Json` package and format the data, then fix the issue.

**Like below**

```
public Task AddToQueue(string userToken)
{
    _queueManager.JoinQueue(userToken, Context.ConnectionId);
    // using JsonConvert.SerializeObject to format the data
    Clients.All.SendAsync("notifyQueuePosition", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(1));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

// the method inside my test service
private void OnNotifyQueuePositionHandler(string queueCount)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(queueCount);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message received from server: {queueCount}");
}
```

**Here is my full code.**

```
using WebApplication2.IServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApplication2.BackgroundServices
{
    public class HubClientService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IQueueManager _queueManager;

        public HubClientService(IQueueManager queueManager)
        {
            _queueManager = queueManager;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + $"   The number of members in the queue: {_queueManager?.UserQueue?.Count}");
                //await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Hub...");

                var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:7245/queueHub").ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    // Log to the Console
                    logging.AddConsole();

                    // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                }).Build();

                hubConnection.Closed += async (error) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed. Reconnecting...");
                    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
                    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                };

                //hubConnection.On<string>("notifyQueuePosition", (queueCount) =>
                //{
                //  Console.WriteLine($"Message received from server: {queueCount}");
                //});

                hubConnection.On<string>("notifyQueuePosition", OnNotifyQueuePositionHandler);


                try
                {
                    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to SignalR Hub.");

                    await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("AddToQueue", "fj294ij29r8jv09258jwr0fj2508f2trvjh2");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error connecting to SignalR Hub: {ex.Message}");
                }

                await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        public Func<string, Task>? NotifyQueuePositionHandler { get; set; }
        private void OnNotifyQueuePositionHandler(string queueCount)  
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(queueCount);
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received from server: {queueCount}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Success Picture**

[image]

**Suggestion**

We need to [enable the signalr client logging to check the detailed message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0#console-logging).

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl("https://example.com/my/hub/url")
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    // Log to the Console
    logging.AddConsole();

    // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
})
.Build();
```